# Is it possible to write a Excel 2003 addin in .Net 3.5 (C#)

Tags: .net, excel-2003

We been given an existing addin (written in .Net 3.0) and have been told that it must be that way because Excel 2003 just can't do .net 3.5.

I have done a quick Google and found nothing that confirms this (although I admit that my Googlefu is weak).  Can anyone tell us if this is the truth?

Answer (score 0):

It's not true. Should work with all .Net versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
VS 2008 (and .NET 3.5) + Excel 2003  = possible
```

Note that you also need VSTO 2005 SE for this to work. Make sure that the target workstation have the runtime version of VSTO 2005 SE.

```
VS 2010 (and .NET 3.5) + Excel 2003 != possible
```

I have not found any documentation indicating this will work. Still looking, but so far no success.

HTH!